# Cannot find out which files were not copied with rsync

Tags: rsync, backup

I copied files using rsync with:

```
rsync -trvh "/media/user/HDD/Arch/" "/media/user/my_drv/Arch/" && rsync -trvhc "/media/user/HDD/Arch/" "/media/user/my_drv/Arch/"
```

After rsync completed its run, the last lines of output were:

```
sent 218.26G bytes  received 1.37M bytes  5.48M bytes/sec
total size is 218.20G  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1338) [sender=3.2.7]
```

After checking which files were not copied, I ran:

```
rsync -trnqhc "/media/user/HDD/Arch/" "/media/user/my_drv/Arch/"
```

and I did not get any output.
I checked the properties of both folders.

For `/media/user/my_drv/Arch/` (destination folder) I got: 
Files: 65697, folders: 19812

For `/media/user/HDD/Arch/` (source folder) I got:    
Files: 65700, folders: 19815

If the source folder has fewer files than the destination folder,
then why does the `rsync -trnqhc` command give me no output
(I expect output with files that were not copied)? 
How can find out which files were not copied from source to destination?

Comment: You're using `-q` (`--quiet`) to suppress messages from the destination part of the transfer process

Comment: @ChrisDavies Thank you. I checked and you are right. Without `-q` my code gives the list of folder and files that were not copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `-q` (`--quiet`) to suppress messages from the destination part of the transfer process. Remove this flag